# Decouple distributional limit from function limit

Tags: functional-analysis, limits, distribution-theory

**Problem:**
Let $T \in \mathcal F'$ be a distribution on some function space $\mathcal F := \{f \in \mathcal C^\infty ~:~ ||f||_{\mathcal F} < \infty \}$ with a certain fall-off behavior defined by the norm (I can elaborate if necessary).
$T$ defined as the distributional limit of an analytic function $T(z) : \mathbb R + i\mathbb R_{>0} \to \mathbb C$ s.t.
$$T(g) := \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int dx T(x + i\epsilon) g(x) \leq C ||g||_{\mathcal F}$$
Now, let $f(\cdot + i\lambda) \in \mathcal F$ analytic for $\lambda \in [0,1]$. I want to show that:
$$T(g) = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int dx~ T(x + i\epsilon) f(x) \overset{!}{=} \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int dx~ T(x + i\epsilon) f(x + i\epsilon). $$
**My thoughts:**
If $T$ was a tempered distribution, I could use the Bros-Epstein-Glaser lemma to write $T(z) = P(\partial_z) G(z)$ for some analytic function $G$ and partially integrate. This is not possible because I have a generalized function space and would have to prove a similar property first.
While this would be a valid approach, I ask myself whether there is a more straightforward way to prove the equality by estimating against the norm
$$\Big|\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int dx~ T(x + i\epsilon) (f(x) - f(x + i\epsilon)) \Big| \leq \cdots \leq C \lim_{\epsilon\to 0} ||f(\cdot) - f(\cdot + i\epsilon) ||_{\mathcal F}.$$
But it is unclear to me how to decouple the $\epsilon$ in $T$ and $f$ to obtain this estimate.